# How can to make a side drawer in a button?

Tags: android, android-studio, button, navigation-drawer

How can I make a button (like sandwich icon) that on click opens a side drawer and turns itself into a cross, and when I click on the cross, closes it.
I don't want the button in an action bar.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? - https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer

Read the documentation

Comment: I don't want the button in action bar.